# Cleaning hanging IPCS in UNIX

Tags: unix

I knew that IPCRM is used to clean hanging IPCS and semaphores for a particumar user by passing the segment id or the semaphore id in either -m or -s option. 
WE NEED TO PASS INDIVIDUAL SEGMENT ID/ SEMAPHORE ID IN -m OPTION. Is there any way to clean ipcs that belongs to a particular user in just one move.

I think shell script could be the way but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Give something like this a try:

```
ipcs -s | awk '$1=="s" && $5=="daveshawley" {print "-s",$2}' | xargs ipcrm
```

You will probably want to substitute the user's real name for mine of course.  You might want to try this question over on http://superuser.com as well